# jQuery - "Loading, Please Wait" On certain Div

Tags: jquery, load, delay, wait

I'm rather new to jQuery, and I'm not too sure which direction to take on this, but I'd like to have some sort of jQuery or Javascript where I can go in, and have a .delay() function of about 3 seconds meanwhile it displays "Please Wait" then shows the div contents. I'm sorry I have no code to show, I only can describe the theory. =/

Thank you for any help provided - Necro

Comment: Just saw some answer lower, they answer the question, but why would you have a "wait loading" if there's nothing loading ? So, I guess you have an ajax call to make or something like that - and this would require some other technique as ajax call end isn't always the same and can't be set using a timer. Could you explain better after what you're waiting to show div content ?

Comment: Because I use another plugin that gets data from google analytics and it takes like 2-3 seconds =]

Comment: Then, using a timeout of 2-3 second won't work as you have no guarantee you'll have your information in 2-3 second - it may, and will, sometime take longer. And, it may sometime take way less than the timeout you set. So, check your plugin for a callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="mydiv">

  <span id="loading">Loading...</span>

  <span id="content" style="display:none;">Bla bla bla</span>

</div>

<script>
setTimeout(function(){

  $("#loading").hide(100); //100 = animation speed in miliseconds
  $("#content").show(100);

}, 3000); //3000 miliseconds = 3 seconds
</script>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dbdAx/

Comment: Perfect! Awesome solution, Thank you. One more question, setting CSS on span ID "loading" will allow me to fade out the background and other stuff like that correct?

Comment: Yes, as it fades out then hides the entire element.

Answer (score 0):

use the following method

```
$("#div").html("Please wait loading");
setTimeout(myfunc,3000);

function myfunc(){
 $("#div").html(yourdata);
}
```

here is the link for a [demo jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/6Tw9U/17/)